# Xcode 6 GM with iPhone 5s (iOS 8 GM) - 0xE8000070

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6 GM Seed (build 6A313) with iPhone 5s (Model A1530, iOS 8 build 12A365). I connect the iPhone via USB lightning cable. But in Xcode, it shows as: "iPhone 5s (unavailable)".

Further investigation: I open **Xcode menu > Window > Devices**, it shows the following error:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.
>
> Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000070)

I reboot and reconnect my iPhone 5s, the same error is shown. This device was used for development in previous Xcode 5, and shows no problem at all.

What should I do? I want to try my apps in iOS 8 device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is resolved after I updated iTunes to version 11.4 via Software Updates.

The Xcode error message is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Xcode-beta 7.1 and want to run app on iOS 9.0 like me you will also get the same error. The solution is:

1. Use corresponding iOS 9.1-beta.
2. Use Xcode 7.0
3. Run on simulator.

Comment: As a note, I had the same issue with Xcode 7.1 beta, and iOS 9.0.2.  When I run Xcode 7 GM and connect the device, it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, during 2 years developing, my phone has several test app with name (null). you can only see a default Xcode app icon in app list in Setting. I had tried updating Xcode, but not work. finally I delete these null name apps, then Xcode - device can connect it without warning sign. Run test app won't get the error in question. only my case. share it in case you encounter in future.