# Device Will not run error iOS 9 Xcode 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode

I recenlty upgraded my device to iOS 9.

The  device will not work in Xcode 7.1, when tying to run  get the error:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.
>   Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000076)

So I updated iTunes and dowloaded Xcode 7.0 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785281/xcode-6-gm-with-iphone-5s-ios-8-gm-0xe8000070), cleaned and built.
No luck.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Nope not a stupid question but a answer, worked the second reboot!

Comment: Unexpected :) Well, I think, I'll make it an answer then :) Glad, that it helped)

Comment: I reboot my device 2 times but still no luck.

Comment: Well，I have also encountered，I try Restart Xcode is working fun

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, it's worth trying to do as the error message proposes: reboot and reconnect the device.

**UPDATE**: it is possible, that two reboots are required. Take a look at comments to this answer.

**UPDATE 2**: If nothing else helps, try restoring the device.

Comment: In my case second time reboot did not help either. As I am writing this, I am going for the 3rd reboot. I've also cleaned the project, deleted the derived data, and rebuilt. Any suggestions? Xcode 7.1 beta, iOS 9.0.1. (3rd reboot no use either - I will try restoring the iPhone).

Comment: @oyalhi, just to clarify: did you try to reconnect the device when you rebooted it? If you did, unfortunately, I have no further suggestions apart from trying to use Xcode 7.0. But it didn't help the OP. Maybe you should create a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) about it.

Comment: Two reboots were necessary for me. Also, on the second reboot I made sure the device was disconnected before rebooting. After it booted I didn't start any other apps (such as AppCode), started Xcode 7, connected the device and it worked. Not sure if any of those other specifics were a factor or if it actually needed a second reboot.

Comment: @metatation, thank you for sharing your experience. I updated my answer.

Comment: @FreeNickname Sorry for the late answer. Yes I did reboot but didn't help. In my case I had to restore the phone.

Comment: @oyalhi, Thank you for sharing your experience. I updated my answer.

Comment: in my case this error was caused by AppCode. Once I quit from AppCode, everything started working

Comment: One more data point: After rebooting the device 3 times and still no joy, I decided to try replacing my frayed USB cord. That worked!

Comment: Re-booting device and restarting XCode worked For me

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem now. I had Instruments open. When I closed it, Xcode would allow my iPhone. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: FWIW, after closing Instruments, I had Xcode Clean, and made a change to a Run Scheme; after that, Xcode was Processing symbol files... and everything was back to normal.

Comment: Same here. Just had to restart Xcode and then it started processing symbols by it self.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation of issue and fix:
- XCode 7 started to monitor connections from applications to the device
- If XCode "does not like" the application or type activity between computer and iOS device - it displays such weird message

Fix - exit all applications that might communicate with iOS device:
- AppCode - most probably it is causing issues
- XCode instrumentation - usually not causing issues but sometimes might do
- iTunes - never seen but it's also probable target

Just to have no side-effects it's better to have device rebooted (with cable detached) and make project Clean prior next attempt to run on a device.

Hope that will save you few minutes and some neurons in your brain

Comment: It was definitely AppCode, in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode store information about different iOS devices that were connected to your computer in /Users/"your home directory"/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport. (OS X El Capitan, Xcode 6.4). I found directory inside it that had the same name as iOS version of iPhone that had such kind of error and delete. 
When I connected my iPhone one more time, Xcode started to copy necessary symbols.
After Xcode finished, I have not receive error again. 
I suppose other Xcode versions (7.3.1, 8.0) store information about iOS Devices in same directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the Apple TV and my problem was the misalignment between Xcode version and the tvOS version on the device.

I had Xcode 9.0 and tvOS 11.0 and everything was working fine, then thanks to automatic updates option enabled on my Apple TV, the device was updated to tvOS 11.1.
That's when I started to get this issue trying to run my application.

The issue was Xcode 9.0 didn't have support for tvOS 11.1, so simply had to upgrade Xcode to version 9.1.

One thing I can suggest, is to check Xcode supported device in the following folder (at least on a Mac):

```
/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

Here you have folders like `iOS DeviceSupport` or `tvOS DeviceSupport` and inside of them you should have the iOS/tvOS version of the device you're trying to use.

If it's not available, very likely it means your Xcode doesn't support (so update Xcode) or you have to install the correct SDK from Xcode.

Anyway, in my opinion, the error message should be a little bit more clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in **xCode7** as it only supports upto **iOS 9.3**. So, you may need to add a *Developer Disk Image* of **iOS version** as of your device. 
You need to goto:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneO‌​S.platform/DeviceSup‌​port/
```

and paste the Developer Disk Image (`iOS version you need`) you just manually downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to install an app onto my AppleTV.  Turns out that I had a beta version of tvOS installed (auto updated).  Once I removed the beta version and installed the GM, the install worked fine, and I was able to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem in Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a) with iPhone 5s(9.3.2). Based on the previous answers, I closed the instrument,simulator and reopen Xcode project twice. Then it work.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I accidentally put a symlink into the assets, which lead to itself. Deleting it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to General setting -> Profile & device management and trust for the developer App.

Answer (score 0):

Just update to latest Xcode/Xcode beta and and update iOS device 
helps with Xcode 11.o beta 6 and iOS 13.1 beta

Answer (score 0):

I spent the whole day with the same issue on iOS 13.0 with Xcode 10.2.1, I updated iOS and Xcode version to iOS 13.1 and Xcode 11.1, cleaned derived folder and restart my Xcode, Mac and iPhone but still got the same error. 
Then I decided to change my usb cable, now it works. So try to change your usb cable, for me I worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your Xcode if that doesn't help than reboot device and reattach.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above solutions, what worked for me is to restore device using iTunes.