# is xcode 8 will support for ios 10.0.2

Tags: xcode

i have updated iphone version 10.0.2 and updated version xcode 8

when i try to run my application successfully build but i am getting an error message like below

" An error was encountered while enabling development on this device."

" Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE800000E)"

I tried rebooting device , restarting xcode and system also nothing is helped
i have correct code signin identity

i don't know it is version problem or other problem

Can any one help me on this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Device Will not run error iOS 9 Xcode 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668810/device-will-not-run-error-ios-9-xcode-7-0)

Comment: I am using xcode 8 beta and ios 10.0.2 in my device, apps runs perfect in my device. I am using personal team for testing in my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

open Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Commond line tools, choose "Xcode 8.0"